# Mysql WHERE problem with comma-separated list

Tags: mysql, sql, denormalized

I need help for this problem.

In MYSQL Table i have a field :

```
Field  : artist_list  
Values : 1,5,3,401
```

I need to find all records for artist uid 401

I do this

```
SELECT uid FROM tbl WHERE artist_list IN ('401');
```

I have all record where artist_list fields values are '401' only, but if i have 11,401 this query do not match.

Any idea ?

(I cant user LIKE method because if artist uid is 3 (match for 30, 33, 3333)...

Comment: You're storing your data in a really bad way, hence you're running into problems.

Comment: Best course of action would be to [read up on normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalisation). I can imagine very costly `REGEXP` answers cropping up here which would be disastrous to performance. `FIND_IN_SET` is a little better, but no substitute for proper normalization.

Comment: Read my answer to [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Short Term Solution

Use the [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT uid 
  FROM tbl 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('401', artist_list) > 0
```

### Long Term Solution

Normalize your data - this appears to be a many-to-many relationship already involving two tables.  The comma separated list needs to be turned into a table of it's own:

### ARTIST_LIST

- artist_id (primary key, foreign key to ARTIST)
- uid (primary key, foreign key to TBL)

Comment: Definitely the best choice. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT uid
FROM tbl
WHERE CONCAT(',', artist_list, ',') LIKE '%,401,%'
```

Although it would make more sense to normalise your data properly in the first place. Then your query would become trivial and have *much* better performance.

Comment: @soulfaya: I'm adding commas to either end of `artist_list` in the query itself to handle that case.

Comment: Fine answer, but `+` is a string concatenation operator in Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.  In MySQL, use the `CONCAT()` function, or else `SET SQL_MODE='PIPES_AS_CONCAT'` and use `||`.

Answer (score 2):

Your database organization is a problem; you need to normalize it. Rather than having one row with a comma-separated list of values, you should do one value per row:

```
uid    artist
1      401
1       11
1        5
2        5
2        4
2        2
```

Then you can query:

```
SELECT uid
  FROM table
 WHERE artist = 401
```

You should also look into database normalization because what you have is just going to cause more and more problems in the future.

Comment: Yes sure... but it's not my question :)