# Display rows via comma values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a comma delimited list like this saved in a mysql table:

```
-----------------
|id | list      |
-----------------
| 4 |12,45,65,4 |
```

Each number in "list" corresponds with an ID in another table.

Is there a way so I can query the other table based on theses IDs and bring up those rows associated with the numbers in "list"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql WHERE problem with comma-separated list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946831/mysql-where-problem-with-comma-separated-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not any efficient way with your current schema. The correct and most efficient way to do it is to change the schema to hold multiple rows like this:

```
-----------------
|id | list      |
-----------------
| 4 |    12     |
| 4 |    45     |
| 4 |    65     |
| 4 |     4     |
```

Then you use `JOIN` operations to connect `4` to every related row in your other table.

This is called database normalization and is a very important topic in database design. Relational database systems are built to handle just this types of problems in an efficient manner.

Comment: I thought so, looks like I'll have to restructure things slightly. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @adamzwakk: Read this, too: **[Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)**