# Select from a range of categories

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql WHERE problem with comma-separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946831/mysql-where-problem-with-comma-separated-list)

I have the next info in a table

```
name     categories
------   -----------
John      1,4
Jim       4,1
JAck      4,1
```

between other.

I want to select all the rows that pertain to category 4, but this statement..

```
SELECT name, categories
FROM `mytable`
WHERE 4 IN (categories)
```

returns only "Jim" and "Jack" but not "John". What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**: Sadly I cant change the structure of the table. I need to use that comma-list style

Comment: You need to stop storing more than one value in a single column.

Comment: Sorry, edited the SQL statement. I had copied it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are storing a comma separated list in a single column. But it you cannot change the table structure, you will want to use `LIKE` to compare the data:

```
select name, categories
from yourtable
where categories like '%4%'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10980/1)

Or you can use the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
select name, categories
from yourtable
where FIND_IN_SET(4,categories) > 0
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10980/2)

My suggestion would be to change your table to not store your data in this comma-separated format, it will cause nothing but problems.

Comment: That will match on 4, 44, etc.

Comment: @OMGPonies yes with `LIKE` that is a problem.  Added a query using `FIND_IN_SET` that will solve that issue

Comment: FIND IN SET was the solution :) Thanks!

Comment: @Dbugger glad you got it working.